# Ryzen 9 3900x Overheating

Tags: cpu, freeze, cooling, temperature

i recently built a new PC with an [Asus ROG Crosshair VIII Hero (WiFi)](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-Crosshair-VIII-Hero-WI-FI/) motherboard and a [Ryzen 9 3900x](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-3900x#product-specs) CPU.  I used the [Wraith Prism cooler](https://www.google.com/search?q=Wraith%20Prism%20cooler) which came with the CPU.

I get high temperatures; sometime the CPU overheats, and my PC crashes. (Currently I am getting about 60 C in idle and 80 under stress).

I thought there might be a problem with the thermal paste pre-applied on the cooler, so I removed it and put a new thermal paste (one pea-sized dot at the center). The temperatures seemed better at first but now the problem persists.

My case is a Sharkoon PURE STEEL and I have one fan at the bottom pulling air in and one fan on the back pushing air out. The case itself does get hot, but not to a level I think should get the CPU to crash from overheat.

What might be the problem? Should I get a better CPU cooler or add more fans to my case?

Comment: The Ryzen 9 3900X should work up to 95C as per the spec sheet linked above, although less is always preferred. May I suggest you measure temps on the RAM and motherboard as well with an inexpensive laser-guided thermometer https://www.harborfreight.com/121-infrared-laser-thermometer-63985.html or similar?

Comment: Symptoms of the crash? Hang, shut-off, bluescreen...? While that CPU does run a bit hot, have you investigated if the problem may lie elsewhere, instead? Maybe the power supply not being beefy enough at high (gpu) loads, or (based on your Mobo) the RAM being OC'd to fickle clock timings?

Comment: Well, so far the crashes has happened when I was not around but I just came to my computer and the I saw a black screen with a message "CPU overheat error, press f1 for setup", then I press f1 and it goes to the bios screen. I have no OC on anything.

Answer (score 1):

First off, install [HWmonitor](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor-pro.html), run a stress test, and upload a temperature graph.  If HWMonitor gives a more reasonable idle temp it might have been a software problem.

- Verify that the fan is, in fact, spinning.
- If you are running any overclocks, disable them.
- Adjust fan curves.
- Remount the cooler and reapply the thermal paste after cleaning the heatsink and CPU with rubbing alcohol.

If all else fails you might need to get a new heatsink.

Comment: I installed HWMonitor and ran Cinebench, The temps went up to 86c towards the end of the test. All the fans are indeed spinning, and I already reapplied the thermal paste. I'll try to readjust the fan curves and see if it helps

Comment: What kind of idle temps is HWMonitor reporting?  86c at load is an acceptable temperature, just a bit high.  60C at idle is really weird though.

Comment: HWMonitor reports 60c on idle. For now I set the Wraith Prism fan to High instead of low, and it seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the voltages being to high on idle. I've got an ASRock X570 
(Ryzen 9 3900x) and it has a BIOS update specifically to address the high voltages which was causing it to run hotter. After the update, it's idle sits between 40 and 50c compared to before it was hovering around the 60c on idle.

A 5 minutes stress test averages 77c which didn't change after the BIOS update.

In regards to the shutting down because of overheating, there's usually a BIOS setting that you can set as the max cut off temp for the CPU. It might be to low and triggering.